# Update lead/contact fields from Campaign Member triggered flow

Tags: visual-workflow, contact, leads, campaign, campaign-member

I am creating a flow to update 2 fields on both lead/contact objects when a campaign member is added/updated. The 2 fields are "oldest campaign" and "newest campaign".

I created 2 variables to hold campaign records called OldestCamVar and NewestCamVar

First I have a decision to see if the campaign that is related to the campaign member that triggered the flow is the correct record type of not

Then I have a Get records element to get Campaign member records that is related to the ContactId and LeadId (I also tried 2nd option to make it equal to the campaign member that triggered the flow) to get the campaigns.

Then I have a loop element to loop through the Collection of records from the element above to assign to a decision. If Current Item.createddated < OldestCamVar.createdDate then assign   currentitem as oldestCamVar. Vice versa for newestCamVar.
Then outside the loop i have 2 update record elements to update Contact's/lead's 2 fields:  "oldest campaign" == OldestCamVar, "newest campaign" == newestCamVar.

The flow is currently not working with error: flow tried to look up records: too many query rows: 50001.

I think the get records element is incorrect but cannot find any alternative to try.

Here is the flow:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this? I have very similar situation in where I am wanting to update my custom checkbox for Leads and Person Accounts when they are in a Campaign.

Comment: I think it was somthing similar to this: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000394583&type=1
I Remember having to work backward from the lead/contact to campaign member.